# custom dojo widget in a loop; html not flowing properly

Tags: dojo, widget

I loop over an array of objects, adding a custom widget to the page each time. I need to put a "space" div atop each widget, and "pageBreak" div at the bottom of each widget. Here is the creation/placement of the widgets inside the loop:

```
var placeIt = true;
array.forEach(data.features,function(feat,i){
    var newDijit = new printDijit({}, domConstruct.create('div'));  
    newDijit.placeAt(dom.byId('printWindow'));
    newDijit.startup();
    if (placeIt){
            newDijit.cNode(domConstruct.create("div",{class:'space',innerHTML:'a'}));
            placeIt = false;
        }else{
            newDijit.cNode(domConstruct.create("div",{class:'break',innerHTML:'a'}));
            placeIt = true;
    }
});
```

Here is the widget:

```
require([
"dojo/parser", 
"dojo/ready",
"dojo/_base/declare",
"dojo/dom-construct",
"dijit/_WidgetBase",
"dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
"dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin"
], function(parser, ready, declare, domConstruct, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin){
    declare("printDijit", [_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin],{
        templateString: dojo.cache(new dojo._Url("printDijit.html")),
        cNode: function(htmlCnode){
            domConstruct.place(htmlCnode,this.domNode.id,'before');
        }
    });     
});
```

Here is the widget template; printDijit.html

```
<div class="printTemplateCls" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="design:'headline'">
<div class="printHeaderCls" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'top'">Top-header</div>
<div class="printInputsCls" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'">Top-right pane</div>
<div class="printBottomPaneCls" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="region:'bottom', gutters:false">
    <div class="printPicCls" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'leading'" style="width:342px">Bottom-left pane</div>
    <div class="printMapCls" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'"></div>     
</div>
```

The html in fireBug looks fine, but the 2nd and onward space/break div's are behind the widget and dont' flow correctly (see screenshot). If the widgets declared everything is good.

Anyone know what's going on here?

[image: div not appearing inline around widget properly]

Answer (score 0):

had to wrap the template in an outer div, like below. I would assume this is because the original root element was also a widget.

```
<div>
    <div class="printTemplateCls" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="design:'headline'">
        <div class="printHeaderCls" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'top'">Top-header</div>
        <div class="printInputsCls" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'">Top-right pane</div>
    <div class="printBottomPaneCls" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="region:'bottom', gutters:false">
        <div class="printPicCls" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'leading'" style="width:342px">Bottom-left pane</div>
        <div class="printMapCls" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'"></div>     
    </div> 
</div>
```